# Campaigns could not be loaded (FCM)

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

when I try to access cloud messaging from the firebase console in any project I always get the error: Campaigns could not be loaded. So I can't create new campaigns or check the status of the current ones

I have already checked connection, I have tried on different devices and projects.

Any idea what is happening? can i do something to fix it?